Does the same hardness with access to different oracles imply equivalent oracles?
If $\textrm{coNP}^{\textrm{NP}}=\textrm{coNP}^{L}$ for $L\in\textrm{NP}$, then does that make $L$ NP-complete?

No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Would you please elaborate @EmilJeřábek? Is there an example of some L, known or suspected to not be NP-complete, for which this holds?
